# how to make an iterable type in type script that has a key value pair

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, typescript-typings

I am using type script and I want to make a type that  represents an object like this
the keys generated are genrated dynamically how do I do that

```
{  dog:true,
cat:true,
x:true
}
```

currently I am just using any but I woud like a proper type

```
 const matches: any= {}
```

i get this error when i try to use

```
 {[key: string]: boolean}
```

```
Type 'string[] | { [key: string]: boolean; }' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterato
```

code that causes this error

```
const docgetter=()=>
    const matches: { [key: string]: boolean } = {}
    const documentFieldKeys = Array.isArray(documentNames) ? documentNames : Object.keys(documentNames)
  

    return [matches, documentFieldKeys]

}



const [matches,kycKeys]=docgetter()

for(key of kycKeys)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "iterable" here?  Does `{[k: string]: true}` work for you?  If so I could maybe write up an answer; if not, then what am I missing?

Comment: no it doesnt for some reason I get the error that I posted with the symbol iterator when I try to use a for in loop

Comment: Please show the code where you’re getting the error.  [mre]

Comment: I just added the code  i realised that if I return an object instead of an array it allows me to do it  now without errors not sure why that is though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `[key : string]`

```
type dict = {
    [key : string] : boolean
}

const o: dict = {
    cat: true,
    dog: true,
    x: false
}
```

Edit:

you didn't specify a type for the output of `docgetter` so typescript inferred it incorrectly as

```
const kycKeys: {
    [key: string]: boolean;
} | string[]
```

You could either fix this by doing

```
for(const key of kycKeys as string[]) {
  console.log(key)
}
```

to let typescript know you are iterating an array and not an object (object would error)

Or you could let typescript know what the output is

fixed version of your code:

```
const documentNames = {
  "a": true,
  "b": true,
  "c": true
}

type output = [
  { [key: string]: boolean },
  string[]
]

const docgetter=() : output => {
    const matches: { [key: string]: boolean } = {}
    const documentFieldKeys : string[] = Array.isArray(documentNames) ? documentNames : Object.keys(documentNames)
    return [matches, documentFieldKeys]

}


const [matches,kycKeys]=docgetter()

for(const key of kycKeys) {
  console.log(key)
}
```

Comment: okay I tried that but I keep on getting this error on some code  when I use that route 
I updated the qestion to show my error